# Two classes reference each other / access UITableViewCell from UITextField inside it's delegate methods?

Tags: objective-c, class, uitableview, delegates, uitextfield

I have a custom UITableViewCell and a custom UITextField, with the text field inside the table view cell.

I need to do some validation on text entered in the field, and display a little tick or cross image in the cell depending on if the text entered was okay.

My table view cell class imports the text field's header, and declares a .textField property which I can use.

My text field class has a class extension (`@class`) of my table view cell, and declares a .cell property, which I'd like to be able to use to access the cell's image, and display / update it to the tick or cross.

The text field's delegate is my view controller, and I'm using `textFieldDidEndEditing` in the following way to attempt to set that image (`validationConfirmation`). However, it's not working, nothing's happening, no error, etc.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? This is a puzzler.

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField 
{
    SignUpTextField *tf = (SignUpTextField *)textField;

    if (textField.text.length < 6) {
        tf.cell.validationConfirmation.hidden = NO;
        tf.cell.validationConfirmation.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cross.png"];
    }
}
```

So here, I'm getting the text field subclass (`SignUpTextField`, or I'm attempting to), and trying to set its cell property's image property. Is this wrong? Messy? Bad practise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to (and you shouldn't) have a cell reference inside textField class. I believe your textField is added as a subview of the cell. Hence in the `textFieldDidEndEditing:` method, you can get the cell using `textField.superview`. Or alternately, you can assign a tag to the textField corresponding to the tableview row that it appears in and access the cell using `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method of tableview where you can use the tag to create your indexpath.

Comment: So how do I get the `superView` property to know that it has a `validationConfirmation` property? It doesn't know that it's a cell, let alone the custom one, it thinks its a `UIView`, no?

Comment: Just cast it (MyCellClass*)textField.superview;

Comment: You can also check the superview type before casting as if([textField.superview isKindOfClass:[MyCellClass class]]){ MyCellClass * cell = (MyCellClass*)textField.superview;}

Comment: I get an uncaught exception `[UITableViewCellContentView validationConfirmation]` if I use casting.

Comment: In that case, your textField is added to cell's contentView instead of the cell. You will have to get the cell using textField.superview.superview.